# Which was the first animated movie in hollywood?

Tags: identify-this-movie, first-appearance, animation

Which was the first animated movie in [Hollywood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood)?

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/772/should-we-downvote)

Comment: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/774/3323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Hollywood history](http://www.hollywoodfilmoffice.org/history.php):

> 1937
>   Disney releases “Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs” – the first animated feature – using the new Three-Strip Technicolor process.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_White_and_the_Seven_Dwarfs_%281937_film%29),

> Based on the German fairy tale by the Brothers Grimm, it is the first full-length cel animated feature film in history, the first produced in full color, the first to be produced by Walt Disney Productions, and the first in the Walt Disney Animated Classics series.

Comment: See http://movies.about.com/od/animatedmovies/a/history-animated-films.htm. Which is correct?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk, From the very same link: 1937 Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs, Walt Disney's initial foray into the world of _full-length animation_ and the _first such production to emerge out of the United States_, is released. That pretty much answers your question.